# GraphQL gets context data and query results from dynamic pages

Tags: gatsby

I have dynamically created pages that include data in a context with the createPage functions:

```
groups.forEach(async node => {
    const id = node.name
   
    actions.createPage({
      path: 'group/'+id,
      component: require.resolve(`./src/pages/groups/index.js`),
      context: { id: id },
    })
  })
....
```

Then I have the resulting page with a graphql query:

```
import * as React from "react"
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'

const GroupPage = ({data}) => {
 
        return (
            <main >               
                <ul>
                    {
                        data.allAgents.edges.map(node => (
                        <li key={node.node.name}></li>
                        ))
                    }
                </ul>
          
            </main>
        )     
}


export const query = graphql`
query($id: String!)  {
    allAgents (filter: { group: {eq: $id } } ) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            name
            group
          }
        }
      }
}
`

export default GroupPage

export const Head = () => <title>Group</title>
```

How can I access the context's page values ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have exposed a prop named `pageContext` what contains the `context` object passed in the `gatsby-node.js` as you can see in the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/#pass-context-to-pages):

> On your pages and templates, you can access your context via the prop
> `pageContext` like this:
>
> ```
> import React from "react"
>
> const Page = ({ pageContext }) => {
>   return <div>{pageContext.house}</div>
> }
>
> export default Page
> ```

In your case:

```
const GroupPage = ({data, pageContext}) => {
 
       console.log("the context is:", pageContext)

        return (
            <main >               
                <ul>
                    {
                        data.allAgents.edges.map(node => (
                        <li key={node.node.name}></li>
                        ))
                    }
                </ul>
          
            </main>
        )     
}
```

Note: if you want to use the `pageContext` to query or to filter your GraphQL query (in your case by `id`), you can get rid of `pageContext` since the value it's automatically lifted to the GraphQL query, hence the `$id: String!` will be automatically used. `pageContext` is useful if you want to display different data.

Note 2:  the loop you're using to create pages should be synchronous: `groups.forEach(node => {...})`